# How do CREATE a new file association in Windows 8?

Tags: windows

I am a new user of Windows 8 and having trouble setting a new file association to open .PPS file.  I can see how to alter settings but .PPS files are not listed and no apparent way to add new listing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking (or press & holding) a .pps file and choosing 'open with' and picking the program that way?  There will be an option to always use that program somewhere near the end of the process (reference here http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/7811-open-change-default-program-windows-8-a.html)  I don't have a Win8 machine to test with immediately, or I'd try and make a full-fledged answer.

Comment: Hi panhandle, yes I have tried the 'open with' options without success.  I have also gone into the apps store which gives some options that claim will open a .pps, but they don't work.  When going into the control panel the .pps extension is not shown.  In XP: I was able to add an unlisted extension but I can't figure out how to do this in WIN8:-(

Comment: Hi panhandle, I have had some advancement - I can now see the .pps extension in my listed document types when opening up my default folders.  The Apps store suggests Microsoft office can open this type of file - I have MSOffice installed but this does not come up when I click for other types of files that may open the extension,  any suggestions??

Comment: When choosing a program to open .PPS with, you will likely have to scroll to the bottom of the list of apps two times in a row and click "find more apps on this computer" which will eventually let you browse to somewhere like C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\POWERPNT.EXE